# page views functionality in angular js

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, meanjs, pageviews

i have setup mean js on my system. all crud operations work fine. my only issue that i cannot get around is to save pageviews when a user visits a page.

when a user visits a webpage like /articles/:articleId , how to increment the counter of page views for that page

here is my simple view function

```
$scope.findOne = function () {
  $scope.article = Articles.get({
    articleId: $stateParams.articleId
  });
};
```

Comment: why don't you use `$location.search.articleId` ?

Comment: @Vineet i do not understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to have a page views field in your mongoose model:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

/**
 * Article Schema
*/
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    pageViews: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    // other fields
```

Then add a `viewCounter()` function to your 'ArticlesController' that increments the `$scope.article.pageViews` property and updates the article.

```
var viewCounter = function () {
  //increment the page views
  $scope.article.pageViews ++
  // update the article record
  $scope.article.$update(function(){
      //handle success
  }, function(err) {
     //handle err
  })
}
//call immediately
viewCounter();
```